# GRUB from Debian to Ubuntu

Tags: installation, grub2

I currently dual-boot Windows 7 and Debian on my computer, both being on separate Hard Drives. I want to overwrite Debian with Ubuntu, but I don't know what will happen to GRUB and Windows loader as a result. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite debian with ubuntu.After installation of ubuntu,boot into it and open the terminal and run the below commands,

```
 sudo update-grub
 sudo shutdown -r now
```

The  `sudo update-grub` command will reinstall your grub to display both `windows` and `ubuntu` operating systems.`sudo shutdown -r now` will restart your pc to display the grub.